# How to filter rows with non ascii encoding characters?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I am dealing with Chinese characters excel. After I read the excel using

```
data = pd.read_excel(file, encoding = 'utf-8')
```

, I can print the file normally (I can read the character).

But, when I want to filter the rows by a value, I got the following error:

`Index = data[data[cols[0]] == "企业下属店铺销售记录"]]`

```
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

I also tried `Index = data[data[cols[0] == u"企业下属店铺销售记录".encode(encoding = 'UTF-8)]]`

But it returns empty dataframe

P.S: I also added `# - *- coding: utf- 8 - *-` at the beginning of the python file

```
This is the return of data.iloc[:, 0]
    : Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
      result = libops.scalar_compare(x, y, op)
    1                 NaN
    2                企业信息
    4                企业名称
    5                客户分层
    6            企业下属店铺名称
    8                店铺名称
    9            名品城海外专营店
    10         anmum海外旗舰店
    11             企业征信信息
    13    近一年是否有欺诈与假货店铺处罚
    14         企业下属店铺销售信息
    16        最近30天日均销售金额
    17       最近30天日均销售订单数
    18        最近30天日均销售件数
    19      企业下属店铺菜鸟仓库存信息
    21      最近30天日均期末库存件数
    22        最近30天日均入库件数
    23      最近30天日均销售出库件数
    24        最近30天平均周转天数
    25         企业下属店铺销售记录
    27               店铺名称
    28           名品城海外专营店
    29           名品城海外专营店
    30           名品城海外专营店
    31           名品城海外专营店
    32           名品城海外专营店
    33           名品城海外专营店
    34           名品城海外专营店
    35           名品城海外专营店
    36           名品城海外专营店
               ...       
    54               货主名称
    55           名品城海外专营店
    56           名品城海外专营店
    57           名品城海外专营店
    58           名品城海外专营店
    59           名品城海外专营店
    60           名品城海外专营店
    61           名品城海外专营店
    62           名品城海外专营店
    63           名品城海外专营店
    64           名品城海外专营店
    65           名品城海外专营店
    66           名品城海外专营店
    67         anmum海外旗舰店
    68         anmum海外旗舰店
    69         anmum海外旗舰店
    70         anmum海外旗舰店
    71         anmum海外旗舰店
    72         anmum海外旗舰店
    73         anmum海外旗舰店
    74         anmum海外旗舰店
    75         anmum海外旗舰店
    76         anmum海外旗舰店
    77         anmum海外旗舰店
    78         anmum海外旗舰店
    79               企业评分
    81               店铺名称
    82               最终得分
    84               店铺名称
    85               最终得分
    Name: 菜鸟金融客户授信初审报告（机密）, Length: 76, dtype: object
```

Comment: data[data[0] == "企业下属店铺销售记录"]]

Comment: @WeNYoBen This gives me keyerror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
Index = data[data.fillna('').iloc[:, 0].str.contains(u"企业下属店铺销售记录")]
```

Comment: I used Index = data[data[cols[0]] == "企业下属店铺销售记录"]] which I want to select the rows where column 0 matching "企业下属店铺销售记录".

Am I correct?

Comment: But I have not defined cols. So, I cannot use cols[0]. This line: Index = data[data[cols[0]] == "企业下属店铺销售记录"]] does not work.

With error: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal

Comment: @JOHN Now? try it

Comment: @U9_Forward I got empty dataframe. I have also added the result of running data.iloc[:,0] just to make sure I am in the right column

Comment: @JOHN It's not there... the one you're searching for

Comment: @U9_Forward I tried Index = data[data[cols[0]] == data.iloc[19,0]]] where data.iloc[19,0] is exactly 企业下属店铺销售记录

still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194730/discussion-between-u9-forward-and-john).